# compare elements of an array of Objects and merge based on a condition

Tags: javascript

After searching, I found many solutions similar to the same idea, but I found it difficult to make the output in a specific format

data:

```js
[
  {
    label: 'General-A-5',
    paymentId: 1,
  },
  {
    label: 'General-A-4',
    paymentId: 1,
  },
  {
    label: 'General-A-3',
    paymentId: 2,
  }
]
```

if paymentId id are the same then merge the label ( **as string but split it with ,**  )

output :

```js
newArray [
  {
    label: 'General-A-5','General-A-4'
    paymentId: 1,
  },
  {
    label: 'General-A-3'
    paymentId: 2,
  }
]
```

thank you

Comment: The requested result features an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function 'find()' to check if you can find a match. If there is a match, push label into an array:

```js
let list = [
  {
    label: 'General-A-5',
    paymentId: 1,
  },
  {
    label: 'General-A-4',
    paymentId: 1,
  },
  {
    label: 'General-A-3',
    paymentId: 2,
  }
];

let newlist = [];

// Simple approach
list.forEach(function(item) {

  // Check if we can find the payment id in the new list
  var match = newlist.find(function(i){
    return i.paymentId === item.paymentId
  })
  
  // If we don't find it, just push it to the new list
  if (!match) {
    newlist.push(item)
  } else {
    // Check if match label is an array
    // Otherwise convert it
    if (!Array.isArray(match.label)){
      match.label = [match.label]
    }
    
    // Now we can just push the label
    match.label.push(item.label)
  }

})

console.log(newlist)
```